# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'x" using azure functions + Python + private repository

Tags: python, import, module, azure-functions

I am having an ModuleNotFoundError error on azure function using python.
I would like to call a function from the private-repository in my HttpTrigger init.py. The actual files of the private-repository are stored inside the src folder after running:

`pip install -r --target=".python_packages/lib/site-packages"  requirements.txt`

The private_repostiroy.egg.link inside .python_packages contains this value:

`/home/runner/work/etl_azure_function/etl_azure_function/src/private-repository`

I have tried multiple solutions to import from the private git repository like :

```
from ..src import private_repository.package
from ..src.private_repository.package import funtion
import private_repository.function
```

I always got an module not found error, altough it's successfully deployed with Github actions.
How can I import the funtions inside private-repository to the httptrigger

```
<project_root>/
 | - requirements.txt
 | - .venv/
 | - .vscode/
 | - .python_packages
 | - HttpTrigger/
 | | - __init__.py
 | | - function.json
 | | - example.py
 | - src
 | | - private_git_repo
 | | | - package 
 | | | |  __init__.py
 | | | |  function.py
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by removing the editable option (-e) in the requirements.txt: